# IE7 and XMLfiles on file system

Tags: xml, ajax, internet-explorer-7, content-type, file-uri

I'm loading a XML file via Ajax using jQuery.

For my tests, I use a file on my file system. It seems all is fine in other browsers but the response headers got by IE has no content-type header. So I get a parsererror. (The XML is valid, I checked it (twice).)

How can I bypass this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a web server (IIS, Apache, etc.) and configure it to serve files from the relevant directory. E.g., http://localhost/myfile.xml .

Alternately, you can use the responseText property and [parse it manually](http://www.w3schools.com/Xml/xml_parser.asp).